# Does the "30 minutes or less" Hat have consequences?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

Wouldn't the hat "30 minutes or less" invite people to ask "simple" questions just to start a flame war and earn it?

One such example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27479588/getting-out-of-the-loop/27479669#27479669 ([screen shot for readers with less than 10K](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiijS.png))

It's a simple question, that prompted 4-5 answers instantly and a heap-load of comments. While there are a lot of such questions normally, wouldn't this encourage even more for no particular use? Could we at least get a way of reporting people with let's say 500+ rep asking how to write an if?

Thanks and keep up the good work :)

Comment: This confused me initially  - You mean the **HAT** "30 Minutes or less" that is part of the Winter Bash - not a badge that is part of the regular site? And if so, yes, I guess I agree there is that possibility.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant Hat. I edited the post. Thanks.

Comment: Example is removed, FYI.

Comment: i noticed... it disappeared as soon as I posted it here. Still, the title is a dead giveaway.

Comment: [Here is a screenshot](http://imgur.com/d2TKCeC) for people who can't view deleted content.